# Spring Batch Job Testing with Mockito

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, spring-batch

I am new to spring batch application. I am writing test cases for spring batch jobs using Junit & mockito.I tried to write the test cases with in memory DB but we are using some oracle specific functions so can't use in mem H2 DB so decided to use mockito to mock DB calls.

My batch job is reading from DB & processing the data & writing back to DB.

jobConfig.java

```
private final JdbcCursorItemReader<LimsExternalLinkDTO> findExternalLinksReader;

@Bean(name = VALIDATE_EXTERNAL_LINK_JOB)
public Job jobValidateExternalLinks() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get(VALIDATE_EXTERNAL_LINK_JOB)
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(stepValidateExternalLinks())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Step stepValidateExternalLinks() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepValidateExternalLinks")
            .<LimsExternalLinkDTO, LimsExternalLinkDTO> chunk(VALIDATE_LINKS_BATCH_SIZE)
            .reader(validateExternalLinksReader)
            .processor(validateExternalLinksProcessor)
            .writer(jdbcBatchItemWriterValidateExternalLink)
            .build();
}
```

Reader.java

```
@Bean
     @StepScope
        public JdbcCursorItemReader<LimsExternalLinkDTO> validateExternalLinksReader(){
            JdbcCursorItemReader<LimsExternalLinkDTO> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setSql(GET_LINK_WHERE_STATUS_NULL);
            reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(LimsExternalLinkDTO.class));
            reader.setFetchSize(BATCH_SIZE);
            reader.setQueryTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            return reader;
        }
```

writer.java

```
 @Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<LimsExternalLinkDTO> jdbcBatchItemWriterValidateExternalLink(){
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<LimsExternalLinkDTO> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql(UPDATE_LIMS_EXTERNAL_LINKS_QUERY);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>());
    return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
}
```

processor.java

private final LinkValidateService linkValidateService;

```
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<LimsExternalLinkDTO, LimsExternalLinkDTO> validateExternalLinksProcessor(){
    return linkData -> {
        System.out.println("processed data :"+linkData);
        linkData.setStatus(linkValidateService.validateLink(linkData.getExternalLink()) ? "VALID" : "INVALID");
        return linkData;
    };
}
```

jobConfigTest.java
I have multiple jobs in the jobconfig class

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes= BatchStepTest.TestConfig.class)
//@SpringBatchTest
@SpringJUnitConfig({LimsReportApplication.class, JobConfiguration.class})
public class BatchStepTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JobRepositoryTestUtils jobRepositoryTestUtils;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        jobRepositoryTestUtils.removeJobExecutions();
        Mockito.when()
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    void testSTep() throws Exception {

        //WHEN
        int bookId = 316;
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("bookId", String.valueOf(bookId))
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(jobParameters);

        //THEN
        Assertions.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED,jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }


    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig extends BatchJobTestConfiguration {
        @Override
        @Bean
        JobLauncherTestUtils getJobLauncherTestUtils() {
            return new JobLauncherTestUtils() {
                @Override
                @Autowired
                public void setJob(@Qualifier("jobValidateExternalLinks") Job job) {
                    super.setJob(job);
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

the above test calls the actual batch job & does the DB calls. How do i mock the DB calls & test the batch job? Please help

Answer (score 0):

> the above test calls the actual batch job & does the DB calls. How do i mock the DB calls & test the batch job?

This is because the test is using the same datasource auto-configured by Spring Boot in your test. If you really need to mock database calls, you need to define a mock datasource and mock all the calls to it (like `getConnection()`, etc).

FYI, oracle provides a free version for developers that you can use for tests: https://www.oracle.com/database/free/get-started/#installing. I would create a datasource with that version for tests.